# Finding the variance problem

Tags: probability, actuarial-science

I am working on the following problem and the explanation was not clear to me, so I am seeking for help.

The following is the problem.

> A fire occurs with a probability of 0.01.  The damage Y given that a fire has occurred is uniformly distributed between 0 and 1 million.  Find the standard deviation of Y. (Let X be the event where the fire occurs or not)

I understand the fact that the formula

$$Var[Y]=Var[E[Y|X]]+E[Var[Y|X]]$$

comes in handy in this situation.

However, the book I am looking at gives me a calculation

$$\frac{10^{12}}{4}(.01)(.99)+\frac{10^{12}}{2}(.01) $$

which puzzles me.

I can see that the right term comes from the variance of a uniform distribution, but I'm not quite clear how the left term came about.

My understanding is that the mean of a uniform is simply the midpoint of the interval, so We should get $\frac{10^6}{2}$ which is for some reason squared in this explanation.

So, I would like 2 things to be answered.

1), Where did the left term come from?

2), I used uniform [0,1] instead of uniform [0,1000000]. If I multiply my result with 1000000, will this still work?

Comment: You are asked to find the standard deviation of **$X$** wich is uniformly distributed (so quite simple). Make clear in your question what you mean by $Y$.

Comment: I did not notice that, thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use the fact that $E[Y] = E[E[Y|X]]$ and $E[Y^2] = E[E[Y^2|X]]$.

$$ E[Y|X] = \begin{cases} 
      \frac{10^6}{2} & X = 1 \\
      0 & X = 0 
   \end{cases}$$

$$ E[Y^2|X] = \begin{cases} 
      \frac{10^{12}}{3} & X = 1 \\
      0 & X = 0 
   \end{cases}$$

Both conditional expectations are random variables as they should be. The rest is just taking the expectation of both of these random variables and using the identity

$$Var(Y) = E[Y^2]-(E[Y])^2$$

Comment: Thank you.  That was very helpful.